# Writing sample for engineering job application

Tags: software-industry, job-search, applications

I came across a job posting for a Machine Learning Analyst, which requires a writing sample as part of the application. I am inclined to apply for it, however am a bit confused as to what a suitable writing sample would be for this. I recently graduated from grad school and have a few reports and essays in mind, nothing related to this job and full of technical jargon and maths! Should I write an essay or something?

UPDATE: A mail to the recruiter elicited this reply: "Your writing sample can be anything that best showcases your writing abilities. No specific topic is preferred and it should be between 1 to 5 pages."

I think I'll play it safe and send a watered down technical write up that anybody can understand.

Comment: You are recently graduated from grad school and you don't have writing sample?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with _few reports and essays in mind, nothing related to this job and full of technical jargon and maths_. Machine Learning Analysis is full of technical jargon and maths.

Comment: A similar thing happened in another job application and the recruiter felt overwhelmed when I sent part of a paper as a sample!

Comment: What is a writing sample in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While submitting a variety of your previous work might be valuable, it might not be what they are asking for.  The best thing to do is contact them and ask for what type of sample(s) they are looking for.  You might have what you need in hand.  If not, then you can create something that fits their needs exactly.

Comment: Shot a mail. Let's see what they reply.

Comment: See?  Was that so hard?  :D

Comment: @user2963623 I see you accepted my answer.  I assume they told you what they wanted?

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 0):

Write an executive summary of one of your reports. Try to choose the report that is best suited for the purpose. Submit the executive summary as a memo cover page for the report. Be sure to make it understandable from a non-technical audience's point of view.